# Calculate Long String Of Input

Tags: python, valueerror

Im learning Python and wanted to code a very short calculation program.

So when I type:

```
result = 4 * 2 * 2

print('result')

16
```

Here I get 16. The Varable result has the value 4 * 2 * 2, right?

But when I type

```
result = input()
(then type 4 * 2 * 2)
print(result)
```

Then I get a ValueError.

Can someone explain?

Comment: I am unable to replicate your error. Are you sure you are typing everything correctly?
If you are trying to calculate the input, use `print(eval(result))`

Comment: `print('result')` will print the string value `result`

Comment: In the first chunk, you are entering Python code.  Python knows how to parse numbers and evaluate expressions in Python code, so it does it.  In the second example, you've just entered a string.  You could have typed `blah blah blah`.  Python sees it just as a collection of characters.  If you want them evaluated, YOU have to do the parsing.

Comment: @Enderbyte09 That was what I was looking for :) Yes I had a typo in the code above (forgot to type that I cast to int) But i didnt know the eval cast :) Thank you very much!